# jQuery UI - remove orange tab border on focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, focus, border

I am trying to remove this border:

[image]

and since it shown only on focus I am not able to find which class to overwrite using the chrome console.

Has anyone done this and knew what is the class that I should overwrite?

Edit: I suppose this is the standard behaviour and [here](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) you can see the example. I am also using Chrome.

Comment: this is behaviour of your browser not related to css , check by opening in firefox

Comment: @rajeshkakawat firefox doesn't display the outline but ie and chrome do. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/4F6z6/ remove li a { outline-color: transparent; } from the css tab to see the difference in chrome or ie

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
li a
{
    outline-color: transparent;
}​
```

Comment: For jquery-ui scope I used `.ui-state-focus a {outline-color:transparent}`

Answer (score 11):

## QUICK SOLUTION:

**The solution if you want to affect the actual .ui element.**

```
.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-hover a {
    outline: none;
}
```

**What the difference was between Anon and Konstantin D's answer?**

Anon rightfully targeted the actual "a tag" inside the "li tag."
Always remember, that tabs(); uses "a tags" inside unsorted list. To actually display the tabs navigation.

## EXAMPLE:

**CSS too affect the outline on li:a tags**

```
.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-hover a {
    outline: none;
}
```

**Fire the jQuery UI Tabs widget**

```
$('#my-tabs').tabs();
```

**Tabs Markup in HTML**

```
<div id="my-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1"></div>
    <div id="tab-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

I like Daniel's solution, I'd just add this to it:

```
.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-hover a, .ui-state-visited a, .ui-state-focus a  {
    outline: none;
}
```

the `.ui-state-visited a` & `.ui-state-focus a` stop it showing the outlining when you click a different tab/ your mouse leaves the hover area

Answer (score 5):

My answer is mix of all above answers simple and short use the following

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a { 
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `ui-state-focus` and `ui-state-active` css classes.

```
.ui-state-focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.ui-state-active {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

In the case of *jQuery UI Tabs* overriding `ui-state-active` should be sufficient.

**Update**: In your case this is not the ui-state-active class but rather the regular anchor outline in webkit. I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ukPW6/4/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in ie9 or chrome, which browser is this for?

Comment: All the browsers. Just make sure you override it after you have included the jQuery UI css, not before. You can find it in the jQuery-UI's css. The section for each component is separated with a comment in the debug version.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to make a difference, maybe it needs !important or maybe something about jsfiddle stops it from working, have a look http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/ukPW6/

Comment: I think that "outline: none;" is what makes the difference, you don't need "border: none;", removing that doesn't make any difference in chrome

Comment: @axrwkr Yeah probably. I put it the for the sake of jQuery UI classes, if the visual was coming from a border. It in fact isn't.

Answer (score 1):

accepted answer works in Firefox but I had trouble with it in Chrome on a Mac.
the outline-style attribute seemed to solve this for me.

```
.ui-state-focus {
        outline-style:none;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @jsh, thanks for adding this. I have never  had the change to test this on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If the solutions above still not working, then it is caused by `box-shadow` property. Try this:

```
.ui-state-focus:focus, .ui-state-focus, li a {
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem.
jQuery mobile applies classes at runtime, I tried above solutions but it didn't worked for me then I removed **ui-shadow** class form `<div data-role="navbar" class="ui-corner-all">`
That fulfilled my requirement.