# Get rid of widget outline?

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

In the screenshot below, the left side is a widget displayed in a normal view.  The right side is the same widget displayed in a modal.  I can't figure out how to get rid of the outline.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: As a StackOverflow User I want to see code so that I can help askers solve problems.

Comment: What code should I post?  The widget view and controller has NO CSS and everything else is stock Durandal.

Comment: It will be something in your widget view (html) file

Comment: If the css is stock, you will need to override the css.

Comment: I had the same problem with tabs. Probably you need to set up outline-color: transparent for this block (approx how it's described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838377/jquery-ui-remove-orange-tab-border-on-focus). Try to look for "outline-color" in your css.

Comment: This is the default browser behavior, when you focus in to some element browser gives it an outline (the outline which you shown in the image is probably set by chrome)

Comment: according to the link by @Kate, you may need to actually add css to specify outline-color: transparent

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate of Kate's link.  That worked perfectly, once I found the right div